# Installing Printer on Remote Computers Using Script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Good Day,

I have prepared below script for local printer installation that are connected to Network having an IP address.

Is it possible to modify this script and make it as to install printers on remote coimputers. My requirement is that if i run this script on my laptop then it will ask me for a Remote ComputerName and after putting the remote computerName the printer gets installed there.

```
   Write-Host "Develop Ineo 363 Printer Installation Initilizing !!"

switch ([system.environment]::OSVersion.Version.Major) {

    5 {$PrnVBSDir = "$env:windir\system32"}
    6 {$PrnVBSDir = "$env:windir\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\"}
}

################################################################################
################# Installing the printer driver ################################
################################################################################
if ([System.IntPtr]::Size -eq 4)
 {  
    Start-Process "RunDll32" -ArgumentList 'printui.dll PrintUIEntry /ia /m "Generic 42BW-4SeriesPCL" /h "x86" /v "Type 3 - User Mode" /f "\\helpdesk-pc\Drivers\Drivers\Printers\Develop 28BW-4\Driver CD-ROM\Driver\Drivers\PCL\EN\Win_x86\KOAYXJA_.inf"' -Wait
    Write-Host "x86 Printer Driver deployment finished !!" -ForegroundColor Green
 }

 else 
 {  
    Start-Process "RunDll32" -ArgumentList 'printui.dll PrintUIEntry /ia /m "Generic 42BW-4SeriesPCL" /h "x64" /v "Type 3 - User Mode" /f "\\helpdesk-pc\Drivers\Drivers\Printers\Develop 28BW-4\Driver CD-ROM\Driver\Drivers\PCL\EN\Win_x64\KOAYXJA_.inf"' -Wait
    Write-Host "x64 Printer Driver deployment finished !!" -ForegroundColor Green 
 }
######################################################################
################## Create the printer port ###########################
######################################################################

$Port = ([wmiclass]"win32_tcpipprinterport").createinstance()

$Port.Name = "Develop-HR"
$Port.HostAddress = "192.168.24.20"
$Port.Protocol = "1"
$Port.PortNumber = "9100"
$Port.SNMPEnabled = $false
$Port.Description = "HR Develop Printer"

$Port.Put()

######################################################################
################# Installing The Printer #############################
######################################################################

$Printer = ([wmiclass]"win32_Printer").createinstance()

$Printer.Name = "Develop-HR"
$Printer.DriverName = "Generic 42BW-4SeriesPCL"
$Printer.DeviceID = "Develop-HR"
$Printer.Shared = $false
$Printer.PortName = "Develop-HR"
$Printer.Location = "HR Department"
$Printer.Comment = "Printer + Photocopier + Scanner"

$Printer.Put()

######################################################################
############################# END ####################################
######################################################################
```

Regards
Abdul Wajid

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this a number of ways, The simplest way I think is to install PSEXEC and store your script in a block called $Code, Then write the script to the target machine and run it with psexec

```
Write-Warning "Run this script using a account that has admin access to the target machine."
$PCName = Read-Host "Computer Name"

$Code = {

switch ([system.environment]::OSVersion.Version.Major) {
5 {$PrnVBSDir = "$env:windir\system32"}
6 {$PrnVBSDir = "$env:windir\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\"}
}

if ([System.IntPtr]::Size -eq 4)
{  
Start-Process "RunDll32" -ArgumentList 'printui.dll PrintUIEntry /ia /m "Generic 42BW-4SeriesPCL" /h "x86" /v "Type 3 - User Mode" /f "\\helpdesk-pc\Drivers\Drivers\Printers\Develop 28BW-4\Driver CD-ROM\Driver\Drivers\PCL\EN\Win_x86\KOAYXJA_.inf"' -Wait
Write-Host "x86 Printer Driver deployment finished !!" -ForegroundColor Green
}

else 
{  
Start-Process "RunDll32" -ArgumentList 'printui.dll PrintUIEntry /ia /m "Generic 42BW-4SeriesPCL" /h "x64" /v "Type 3 - User Mode" /f "\\helpdesk-pc\Drivers\Drivers\Printers\Develop 28BW-4\Driver CD-ROM\Driver\Drivers\PCL\EN\Win_x64\KOAYXJA_.inf"' -Wait
Write-Host "x64 Printer Driver deployment finished !!" -ForegroundColor Green 
}

$Port = ([wmiclass]"win32_tcpipprinterport").createinstance()

$Port.Name = "Develop-HR"
$Port.HostAddress = "192.168.24.20"
$Port.Protocol = "1"
$Port.PortNumber = "9100"
$Port.SNMPEnabled = $false
$Port.Description = "HR Develop Printer"

$Port.Put()

$Printer = ([wmiclass]"win32_Printer").createinstance()

$Printer.Name = "Develop-HR"
$Printer.DriverName = "Generic 42BW-4SeriesPCL"
$Printer.DeviceID = "Develop-HR"
$Printer.Shared = $false
$Printer.PortName = "Develop-HR"
$Printer.Location = "HR Department"
$Printer.Comment = "Printer + Photocopier + Scanner"

$Printer.Put() }

$Code | Out-File \\$PCName\C$\Logs\install-printer.ps1 -Width 230 -Force #Pipe the code block into a ps1 file on the target computer
Start-Process "C:\Psexec.exe" -ArgumentList "\\$PCName -s Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Logs\install-printer.ps1 -Verb runas" -Wait #Start PSExec and run the ps1 file
#ToDO:Clean up the target machine, remove the file afterwards.
```

[PSEXEC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx)